# Mysql: inserting semi-distinct entries into another table

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table called `logs`.

logs has a few columns, two of which are called `user_id`, a signed integer, and `timestamp`, which is a timestamp.

The logs table can have several timestamps per user_id.

I want to transfer over this data to a table called `users`, which has several columns, two of which are called `user_id` and `last_date`.

What I need to do is to populate the users table's `last_date` column with, you guessed it, the last `timestamp` of the logs table, for each user_id.

I know how to insert a selection from a table but I can't figure out how to get a list of distinct user_ids along with their timestamps, filtered out by the last timestamp.

E.G.

`SELECT DISTINCT (user_id), timestamp FROM logs GROUP BY timestamp DESC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you do not need `distinct` when using `group by`.  Second, you want to aggregate by `user_id`.  Third, you need an aggregation function for `timestamp`:

```
SELECT user_id, max(timestamp)
FROM `log`
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY max(timestamp) desc;
```

I'm not sure if the final `order by` is needed, but it conforms to the query in the question.

This assumes that "last timestamp" means the largest time stamp.  If this isn't the case, then edit your question with sample data.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(timestamp) as last_date FROM `logs` GROUP BY user_id;
```